# Getting GC overhead limit exceeded error while moving data from temp table to staging table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

we have a 1 gb CSV file which we are trying to load into hive tables. First we move the data to the temp table using the below hive query.This file conatins 656 columns.

```
use ${hiveconf:database_name};
set table_name = table_name;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH "${hiveconf:path}" OVERWRITE INTO TABLE ${hiveconf:table_name};
```

Then we move the data from tmp table to staging table using the below query.

```
use ${hiveconf:database_name};
SET mapred.job.queue.name=root.dev;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode = 500;
SET hive.variable.substitute.depth=100;
SET PATTERN='\\^';
SET REPLACEMENT='';
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE STAGING_TABLE partition(FILE_NAME="${hiveconf:PARTITION_BY}")
                                        SELECT 
                                        COLUMN1,
                                        COLUMN2,
                                        ..
                                        COLUMN656
                                        FROM TEMP_TABLE;
```

While executing the above script I get the below error.

```
 

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-0.13/conf/hive-log4j.properties
OK
Time taken: 0.486 seconds
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator Starting Job = job_1455125666889_268626, Tracking URL = 
Kill Command = /opt/mapr/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1455125666889_268626 Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 7; number of reducers: 0
2016-03-29 01:46:37,753 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-03-29 01:47:11,979 Stage-1 map = 14%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 599.7 sec
2016-03-29 01:47:15,076 Stage-1 map = 29%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 669.22 sec
2016-03-29 01:47:18,169 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 738.77 sec
2016-03-29 01:47:19,200 Stage-1 map = 57%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 753.23 sec
2016-03-29 01:47:46,028 Stage-1 map = 71%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1366.8 sec
2016-03-29 01:47:47,067 Stage-1 map = 79%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1388.92 sec
2016-03-29 01:47:51,216 Stage-1 map = 86%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1429.25 sec
2016-03-29 01:47:52,245 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1470.08 sec MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 24 minutes 30 seconds 80 msec Ended Job = job_1455125666889_268626
Stage-4 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Stage-3 is selected by condition resolver.
Stage-5 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Launching Job 3 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator Starting Job = job_1455125666889_268633, Tracking URL = 
Kill Command = /opt/mapr/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1455125666889_268633 Hadoop job information for Stage-3: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2016-03-29 01:48:01,025 Stage-3 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-03-29 01:49:01,552 Stage-3 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 240.81 sec
2016-03-29 01:49:11,808 Stage-3 map = 16%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 300.08 sec
2016-03-29 01:49:17,956 Stage-3 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-03-29 01:50:18,409 Stage-3 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 243.14 sec
2016-03-29 01:50:25,577 Stage-3 map = 16%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 284.99 sec
2016-03-29 01:50:31,717 Stage-3 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-03-29 01:51:32,060 Stage-3 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 255.38 sec
2016-03-29 01:51:41,264 Stage-3 map = 16%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 302.65 sec
2016-03-29 01:51:47,396 Stage-3 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-03-29 01:52:47,713 Stage-3 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 230.81 sec
2016-03-29 01:53:03,040 Stage-3 map = 100%,  reduce = 0% MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 3 minutes 50 seconds 810 msec Ended Job = job_1455125666889_268633 with errors Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_1455125666889_268633_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1455125666889_268633

Task with the most failures(4):
-----
Task ID:
  task_1455125666889_268633_m_000000

-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: GC overhead limit exceeded

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Job 0: Map: 7   Cumulative CPU: 1478.78 sec   MAPRFS Read: 0 MAPRFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Job 1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 230.81 sec   MAPRFS Read: 0 MAPRFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 28 minutes 29 seconds 590 msec
```

If the file size is less than 300 mb , we are not facing any issues with the above query. If the file size is above 300 mb we are getting the GC limit issue.

When we asked the infra team we are told to rewrite our query.Can someone please explain what we are doing wrong in the above query?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The link http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201405.mbox/%3C5300D8DD-F3FA-45AB-A274-19B20FA9AE11%40hortonworks.com%3E contains the answer to the above question